# Sending parameters to view when submitting a form in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to send some parameters when submitting a form in Django and I'm not sure how to do this.

Right now I have a form inside a page(Page A) allows filtering-- so my url for that page looks like this example.com/view-students?grade=5&teacher=smith

Inside that page I have a pop-up that allows a user to delete a student. When the user confirms that they want to delete a student, the form is submitted-- this directs to another view that takes care of the deleting. Then, I immediately redirect back to Page A.

The problem is that I need the parameters (?grade=5&teacher=smith) back in my url to redirect correctly. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have ?

Comment: Probably need more details to give a real solution, but two things come to mind.  `javascript.history(-1'ish);`  or in the case you have context `return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())`...  that that could be way off.

Comment: No problem, I will add more details/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to pass variables from one view to another, you can **set the value of `grade` and `teacher` in the session** and then use this values in your second view to redirect it properly.

```
request.session['grade'] = 5
request.session['teacher'] = 'smith'
```

In your 2nd view, you can just do the following to access the value of `grade` and `teacher`:

```
grade = request.session['grade']
teacher = request.session['teacher']
```

Comment: wow, i totally overlooked session variables.. This works, i just had to add a bit of conditional logic (case where there's no parameters in the url).

Comment: In case anyone has trouble retrieving the value from the parameters in the url: grade = request.GET.get('grade', '') ... From there, you can use the solution above and store it in a session variable. request.session['grade'] = grade

Comment: Yes, in the 2nd view, you can access the value from the session.

Comment: In the view where you have access to grade and teacher, set their values in the session and then in your 2nd view, access those values.